# Filtering Streambuf

Tags: c++, stream

Today's code is a filtering streambuf (and associated stream type) to automate word-wrapped output in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <iomanip>

class widthbuf: public std::streambuf {
public:
    widthbuf(int w, std::streambuf* s)
        : indent_width(0), 
        def_width(w), 
        width(w), 
        sbuf(s), 
        count(0) 
    {}

    ~widthbuf() { overflow('\n'); }

    void set_indent(int w) { 
        if (w == 0) {
            prefix.clear();
            indent_width = 0;
            width = def_width;
        }
        else {
            indent_width += w; 
            prefix = string(indent_width, space);
            width -= w; 
        }
    }

private:

    typedef std::basic_string<char_type> string;

    // This is basically a line-buffering stream buffer.
    // The algorithm is: 
    // - Explicit end of line ("\r" or "\n"): we flush our buffer 
    //   to the underlying stream's buffer, and set our record of
    //   the line length to 0.
    // - An "alert" character: sent to the underlying stream
    //   without recording its length, since it doesn't normally
    //   affect the a appearance of the output.
    // - tab: treated as occupying `tab_width` characters, but is 
    //   passed through undisturbed (but if we wanted to expand it
    //   to `tab_width` spaces, that would be pretty easy to do so
    //   you could adjust the tab-width if you wanted.
    // - Everything else: really basic buffering with word wrapping. 
    //   We try to add the character to the buffer, and if it exceeds
    //   our line width, we search for the last space/tab in the 
    //   buffer and break the line there. If there is no space/tab, 
    //   we break the line at the limit.
    int_type overflow(int_type c) {
        if (traits_type::eq_int_type(traits_type::eof(), c))
            return traits_type::not_eof(c);
        switch (c) {
        case '\n':
        case '\r': 
            {
                buffer += c;
                count = 0;
                sbuf->sputn(prefix.c_str(), indent_width);
                int_type rc = sbuf->sputn(buffer.c_str(), buffer.size());
                buffer.clear();
                return rc;
            }
        case '\a':
            return sbuf->sputc(c);
        case '\t':
            buffer += c;
            count += tab_width - count % tab_width;
            return c;
        default:
            if (count >= width) {
                size_t wpos = buffer.find_last_of(" \t");
                if (wpos != string::npos) {
                    sbuf->sputn(prefix.c_str(), indent_width);
                    sbuf->sputn(buffer.c_str(), wpos);
                    count = buffer.size()-wpos-1;
                    buffer = string(buffer, wpos+1);
                }
                else {
                    sbuf->sputn(prefix.c_str(), indent_width);
                    sbuf->sputn(buffer.c_str(), buffer.size());
                    buffer.clear();
                    count = 0;
                }
                sbuf->sputc('\n');
            }
            buffer += c;
            ++count;
            return c;
        }
    }

    size_t indent_width;
    size_t width, def_width;
    size_t count;
    size_t tab_count;
    static const int tab_width = 8;
    string prefix;

    char_type space = static_cast<char_type>(' ');

    std::streambuf* sbuf;

    string buffer;
};

class widthstream : public std::ostream {
    widthbuf buf;
public:
    widthstream(size_t width, std::ostream &os) 
        : buf(width, os.rdbuf()), 
        std::ostream(&buf) 
    {}

    widthstream &indent(int w) { 
        buf.set_indent(w); 
        return *this; 
    }
};

#ifdef TEST

int main() {
    widthstream out(30, std::cout);
    out.indent(10) << "This is a very long string that will wrap to the"
        " next line because it is a very long string that will wrap to "
        "the next line.\n";
    out.indent(0) << "This is\tsome\tmore text that should not be indented "
        "but should still be word wrapped to 30 columns.";
}

#endif
```

As you can see from the included demo/test code, along with word-wrapping to a specified width, this supports arbitrary indentation.

Comment: I would create `std::codecvt` facet specialization. Then you can apply it to any stream you like. [Here is one for indenting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1397588/14065)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked over this code carefully and came up with a number of aspects that might be considered for future enhancements.

### Write initializers in declaration order

Since initialization is done in declaration order rather than the order that initializers are written, it's helpful to readers of your code to make sure that initialization order matches declaration order.  In the `widthbuf` constructor, the code is like this:

```
widthbuf(int w, std::streambuf* s)
    : indent_width(0), 
    def_width(w), 
    width(w), 
    sbuf(s), 
    count(0) 
{}
```

But because of their declaration order, `width` actually gets initialized before `def_width` and `count` before `sbuf`, so it would be one fewer opportunity for misunderstanding if these were arranged in declaration order.

### Don't rely on promises not actually made

The constructor order comment also applies to the constructor of `widthstream` and the order of the underlying base class `std::ostream` and `widthstream::buf` but in this particular case it's not actually guaranteed to work:

```
widthstream(size_t width, std::ostream &os) 
    : buf(width, os.rdbuf()),
    std::ostream(&buf)
{}
```

It looks as though the intent was to initialize `buf` first and then use it to construct the underlying `std::ostream` but that's not actually what happens.  In fact, the code is passing a reference to a not-yet-fully-constructed `buf` which is unusual but not technically illegal as long as the constructor receiving the reference does not do anything with it, such as dereference it, attempt to access member functions, etc.  Because the underlying base class `std::ostream` makes no such guarantee not to dereference, this code is prone to failure.

This can be easily demonstrated by replacing `std::ostream` in `widthstream` with `evil_ostream` which attempts to get the locale of the `std::streambuf` that is the base class of `widthbuf`:

```
class evil_ostream : public std::ostream {
public:
    evil_ostream(std::streambuf *buf) : std::ostream(buf) { 
        std::cout << "(ab)using reference to unconstructed buf\n"; 
        auto loc = buf->getloc();   // kaboom!
    }
    virtual ~evil_ostream() {};
};
```

The line that attempts to fetch the locale causes a segfault because the underlying object is not actually completely constructed.

### Handle `wstring` or state that you don't

The code does not seem to be happy with `std::wstring` instead of `std::string` as input.  This isn't necessarily a problem, but it should be stated, at least in comments that wide characters are not handled by this code.  Alternatively, adding support for `wchar_t` strings could probably be done with the use of templates.

### Use all of the required `#include`s

The type `std::basic_string<char_type>` is used but its declaration is in `#include <string>` which is not actually in the list of includes.

### Consider using `facet`s

As mentioned by @LokiAstari in comments, it *might* be appropriate to consider the use of a `facet` for this purpose.  The reasons one might do so would include the fact that formatting of text representation is a particular strength of the `facet` approach.  However, there are also reasons one might not do so, including the fact that `facet`s typically incorporate a cultural apect that isn't really appropos here and that `facet`s tend to have complementary input and output aspects which also aren't really gemane to this application.

Comment: For your second section, the solution would be to use the Base from Member idiom - the [wiki example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member) of which even uses `ostream`!